# Конструктор форм в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.

Есть 7 форм, в которых есть от 20 до 50 различных полей. 
Каждое поле при обработки формы должно проходить валидацию, возможно как-то преобразовываться и сохраняться в определнное поле определённой модели.

При таких объемах код в контроллере и шаблоне будет массивным, громоздким и неудобным для дальнейшего изменения.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, я хотел сделать что-то типо массива, в котором записаны поля и их параметры, такие как:

- тип поля (текст, число, чекбокс и т.д. - название заготовленного
  шаблона)
- имя поля (аттрибут name)
- название поля (label)
- возможные значения (для select и прочих)
- подсказка
- правила проверки
- как обрабатывать при сохранении
- куда сохранять, в какую таблицу и в какое поле
- и т.д.

Таким образом можно было бы настроить форму в одном месте, и в случае чего быстро и безболезненно добавлять, изменять или удалять какие-то поля.

Подскажите, решали ли вы такую задачу, если да, то как? Каким образом лучше всего реализовывать это именно в Laravel, с учётом всех его возможностей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендовал бы вынести весь код формы в отдельный трейт и подключать его соответственно к необходимому контроллеру.

Например создайте новый трейт FormContruct, добавьте весь ваш код туда:

```
trait FormContruct
{
// ваш код
}
```

И уже в классе вашего контроллера подключать его:

```
class SomeController extends Controller 
{
   use FormContruct;

   // ваши методы
}
```

P.S.
Учитывая большое количество полей в формах, есть смысл просто получить все их значения в массив:

```
$input = $request->all();
```

И уже дальше работать с этим массивом.

Comment: Полезная статья для "облегчения" ваших контроллеров, моделей. Возможно, что-то еще захотите вынести в отдельные модули. https://blog.armen.im/ru/php-traits-%D0%B2-Laravel/

Comment: Про HTTP запросы - http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization